# Sub Vector space

Tags: vectors

Is the following set Sub vector space of $R^2$ ?

$$K=\{(x y) \in R: x^2+y^2=1\}$$

Well, it was easy to prove that the set is not empty. But Problem is if i take $u,w \in K$. 
How to prove also $u+w \in K$ ?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

thanks

Comment: Is the origin in $K$?

Comment: What does $\frac xy $ mean? should it mean $(x,y)$

Comment: @lulu: It is if OP really meant what he wrote. $0=\frac01$, and $0^2+1^2=1$, so $0\in K$. That is to say, take $x=0$ and $y=1$.

Comment: @MPW  It is hard to guess what the OP meant.  I took it to mean $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ such that $\frac xy\in \mathbb R\;\&\;x^2+y^2=1$ in which case the origin isn't in $K$.  I don't understand what you think the OP meant...I agree that $(0,1)\in K$ but $(0,0)$?

Comment: @suugiio2  Can you clarify your question?  As you can see from the comments, nobody is sure what you mean.  As it stands, the question seems trivial (if $\vec u=(0,1)$ then $\vec u\in K$ but $\vec u +\vec u=(0,2)$ is not in $K$).  But maybe you meant something else?

Comment: If "$\frac{x}{y}$ is really intended, the K is not even a sub[b]set[/b] of $R^2$ so cannot be a subspace.

Comment: Well, My bad guys. It was tuple. not Division

Comment: Oh dear. I guess I'll mark my answer as invalid since you're changing the question. However, $K$  as oringinally stated *is* a subspace (regarding it as lying in the first factor, as I indicate in my answer).

Comment: @lulu: I was taking it literally to mean real numbers satisfying the given condition.

Comment: So sorry guys. Thank you MPW though

Comment: What i did is this: Since it is the equation of circle with radius 1. K is not empty. Just take x=1 and y=0. it satisfies that K is not empty.  If i take any two vectors $u= (u_1,u_2)$ $w=(w_1,w_2)$ with the same property. It must also satisfy this property $(u_1+u_2)^2+(w_1+w_2)^2 =1$

Comment: @sugiio2  Ok, so then do you agree that $(0,0)$ is not in $K$, so it can't be a subspace?  Alternatively, $(0,1)\in K$ but $(0,1)+(0,1) \not \in K$

Comment: i agree with that. lulu

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Question was changed, this answer is no longer valid.

<strike>If you are thinking of $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$, then yes. $K$ is essentially the real line.</strike>

Clearly $K\subset \mathbb R$. Now suppose $r\in \mathbb R$. Write $r=\frac{r/\sqrt{1+r^2}}{1/\sqrt{1+r^2}}$, and note that
$$\left(r/\sqrt{1+r^2}\right)^2 + \left(1/\sqrt{1+r^2}\right)^2 = 1$$
So $R\subset K$.

**Note 1:** $K$ essentially consists of all real slopes of line segments connecting the origin to points on the unit circle.

**Note2 :** The potential "problem" of $y=0$ isn't really a problem because $1/0\notin \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

the set $K$, can not  be a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$ because the
zero vector is not in there. and another $ K $ is the circle of
radius $1$ in the actual plan, it is not stable by the addition.